# Error en @Override

Tags: android

No tiene mucho que instale el programa, al momento de querer empezar me sale este problema "Method does not override method from its superclas" . [image: A]

Tengo instalado todo correctamente y aún así no comprendo cual es el problema, busqué soluciones pero no encontré la que me permitiera ayudar. Muchas gracias por su atención y ayuda.

Comment: Te recomiendo en ves de subir imágenes para representar código subas el código como tal, el editor de texto tiene esta herramienta al momento de subir tus preguntas. Saludos!

Comment: Agrega que clases importas, agrega más información a tu pregunta. revisaste en los recursos si tienen algún error?, revisa [ask], saludos.